Does the following not compile because RVO has been disabled when returning a pointer or reference?
I have a class that is only moveable, and I can't return it when I have a pointer to it or reference to it:
struct TestCase
{
    TestCase() {}
    TestCase(const TestCase&) = delete;
    TestCase(TestCase&&) {}
    TestCase& operator=(const TestCase&) = delete;
    TestCase& operator=(TestCase&&) { return *this; }
};

TestCase funcReturningOnlyMovableType()
{
    TestCase test_case;
    TestCase* ptr_test_case = &test_case;
    TestCase& ref_to_test_case = test_case;

    return test_case; // WORKS
    //return *ptr_test_case; // DOESN'T WORK COPY CONSTRUCTOR IS DELETED
    //return ref_to_test_case; // DOESN'T WORK COPY CONSTRUCTOR IS DELETED
}

int main()
{
    TestCase test_case = funcReturningOnlyMovableType();
}

Is this because RVO is disabled when using a pointer or reference to return the object? And therefore the copy constructor has to be called?
This happened to me on MSVC, but I have since checked Compiler Explorer and the same thing happens in GCC and Clang.

What compiler have you tried with? What version of the compiler? What version of the C++ standard?

@Someprogrammerdude Oh sorry, I was MSVC, then I tried on Compiler Explorer and exactly the same thing happened on Clang and GCC.

Note that return test_case; requires a non-deleted move constructor since NRVO is not mandatory. RVO, like in return TestCase{};, doesn't require move or copy constructors and works even if you've deleted both (since C++17).

Side note: both the pointer return and the reference return refer to test_case which no longer exists.

@doug At the point it's returned it exists, I don't know what you mean. It doesn't exist until the end of the scope.

@Zebrafish You're right. Sorry.

This has nothing to do with RVO but is instead how return handles function local objects.
When you have a function local object and you return it the compiler first treats the object as an rvalue for the purposes of overload resolution.  This allows your move constructor to be called and moved test_case into the return object.
When you access the object through a pointer or reference that can't happen as those expressions yield an lvalue so the return statement has to treat the object as an lvalue which prevents the move from happening.

... and the workarounds being return std::move(*ptr_test_case); / std::move(ref_to_test_case);

In the C++17 standard this behavior can be found in [class.copy.elision]/3, but I can't find that paragraph in the current draft of the language.  I think I remember it being updated for C++23 but I can't find it.

Were you looking for http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.unqual#4 ?

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yes I was.  Thanks
